# Is there an antonym to simulated?

Tags: word-request

Is there an antonym to simulated? For example: This event wasn't simulated in a computer, it happened for real in the real world. I am looking for a verb that means the opposite of simulated, but I don't think it exists. Is there a phrasal verb perhaps? Is there any other more succinct way to express this? I am looking for a technical term to use in an essay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply say, '**real**.'

> This event wasn't simulated in a computer, it was **real**.